# How many Puma Cluster Workers are recommended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, puma

How many Puma Cluster Workers are recommended?
What if I would like to run multiple Pumas on one Server regarding the Puma Cluster Worker count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no recommended number of Puma workers, it's a matter for tuning your code and resources to match your application's load.

Running multiple Puma instance on a single server is exactly what the cluster mode was designed for, so it's a good idea. But note that puma allows for two different levels of concurrency configuration - number of threads per worker and number of workers - it's important to understand each of this options to get the most out of your resources.

I suggest reading the following:
https://github.com/jrochkind/fake_work_app

It's a comparison of various Ruby web servers but I'm referencing it here because it explains very well the level and method of concurrency each of the servers supply, including puma.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. At the moment I am running 4 Apps on my server each with cluster mode. My Problem is that all of the 4 workers of one App are going to 100% CPU Usage after approximately one day. After a restart everything works fine in the beginning but the problem reoccurs. Do you have any Idea? Would it be the right way to use for example 8 workers to try to solve the problem?

Comment: Kinda hard too tell based on the scarce info I have.... Your situation sounds a complicated due to the fact you're sharing resources among number of apps - how do you know, for example, which of the apps is hogging the CPU? I general I don't think adding any resource consuming threads is a good idea if you're having a resource problem :/

Comment: The workers are dedicated to one app. So it should be this app. Would it be more recommended not using the cluster mode? At the moment I dont have an idea how to identify the problem :/

Comment: its a while ago, but my problem was a very very deep bug in my code, which i resolved after a lot of debugging. Great answer indeed.